# Fixing high latency on a single device on a wired LAN

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan, latency

I have a device on a wired LAN that has really, really high latency on a ping. 599ms and higher. I cycled power to the device and the latency dropped back to <1ms. That lasted for about three days and it is back to 599ms. On a side note it has run fine for two years and just now started acting up.

As far as debug goes, could it be in the cable or the switch? My guess would be the device itself but going back to the manufacturer is going to be a huge pain in the rump and I don't want to do it until it is a last resort.

How can I resolve this latency problem?

Comment: If rebooting the devices fixes it temporarily, that points a lot of fingers at the device, not the switch or cable. If you unplug just the Ethernet cable for a few seconds and then plug it back in (without rebooting the device; hopefully we're not talking about a PoE-powered device here), does that clear up the problem? If not, then that's additional evidence it's not the switch, because dropping link on the port should reset the state of the port pretty well.

Comment: What kind of device is this? What OS does it run? Do you have any way to see CPU usage or other activity stats on this device? Is there any way to see any kind of system / console / error / status log? What about your switch — is it a managed switch that you can see stats for that port? Does the latency problem show up in normal operation (i.e. not ping)? I feel like you should edit your Question to try to provide a lot more detail about your situation and what you've tried. So far we have a clear problem statement but not much more to go on.

Comment: It isn't PoE. It is a very proprietary environmental unit. Can't do anything with it. No OS. It sits there and collects data. The PCs poll it and display info in a bar graph. The way we know it freaks out is that the bar graph is not contiguous. That is all there is to go on. The latency to the switch is fine but the latency to the "box" is astronomical. Will try unplugging the network cable and report back.